# Groovy DSL vs Antlr for human readable configuration file

Tags: selenium, groovy, antlr, dsl

Hope this is not a stupid question.

For Regression testing, I wrote a small tool which uses Selenium to bring up the screen, verifies the loaded screen data against the database (multiple tables) and generates a report with screenshots (in case of errors).

Being a lazy guy that I am, instead of writing one class for single use case (~60 use cases for a screen), I wrote one single class which can accept multiple configuration files as a parameter.  **The configuration file dictates the flow of the testcase (in steps), the mapping of the xpath/id of the form field against the database query, the queries etc.**

It all works well but the problem is that the configuration file is an XML. Neighboring projects are interested and would like to use the tool and I want them to easily understand the tool and customize to their needs. XML, in my opinion, is inappropriate here. Besides, the mapping between screen form fields and database columns are the same for many testcases which use the same screen for different use case combination.  It would be great if there could be inheritance there instead of copying the content.

So, I am hoping to write a small DSL which goes something like

```
open application

load editClient window

switchTo generalTab

verify generalTab{

    if dataValidFor clientName then addInfoToReport else addErrorToReport
    if dataValidFor clientAddress then addInfoToReport else addErrorToReport
    if confidentialData visible then addInfoToReport else addErrorToReport

}
...

...
```

You get the idea. **All I am planning to do is to translate the DSL to Java (or Groovy, if need be) method calls in the background.** I understand that the requirement is not that huge to warrant a powerful library like Antlr. However, my experience with Groovy is very limited that I don't even know whether it is possible in Groovy.

I referred to this [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/glaforge/groovy-dsls-from-beginner-to-expert-guillaume-laforge-and-paul-king-springone2gx-2011) and it looks amazing. However, I am worried about the capability to include blocks in the DSL as in

```
verify generalTab{
...
}
```

PS :  I am no expert in Lexers and Parsers (non-computer science under-grad) but I managed to self-learn ANTLR and played around with it for few weeks couple of years ago. Again, I have very little experience with Groovy.

Comment: The bit you'll struggle with in a DSL is the `if datavalidfor clientname then` as Groovy already knows how to handle `if`, and it's not like this :-/

Comment: PS: Have you seen [Geb](http://www.gebish.org/)?

Comment: Geb looks neat @tim_yates but now that something like a framework (data validation, reporting etc) has already been developed, just the configuration as a DSL would be great. That said, next time I am up to something with Selenium, Geb would definitely be one of my top options.

Comment: Noted the "if" issue. Let me go through the Groovy DSL docs and figure out what exactly the issue is. As always, I can play with the syntax of the DSL.

Comment: Using Groovy for your DSL would do just fine, but ANTLR wouldn't be overkill at all, IMO.

Comment: whichever way you go, make sure you have a complete specification for the language first. it's much harder to retro-fit things you forgot in the original spec than it is to get them in on the first pass...

Comment: @tim_yates, you can safely insert that comment under most questions! :)

Comment: trade "if" for "when", to avoid groovy's "if" syntax :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also no expert in groovy's DSL, but have been playing with it a bit and i think your case is doable. But it is large.

Writing

```
verify generalTab { ... }
```

Groovy seems to resolves to

```
verify( generalTab({ ... }) )
```

so a way near what you want would be to intercept method missing call ('generalTab' seems like a html component id to me, please correct me if i'm wrong).

You will need: a `verify()` method and a `methodMissing()` method.

Your `if` and `else`s... uh, can we swap it for `when` and `otherwise`? Just to avoid groovy's own reserved words ;-)

Those double words after the `if` make the whole thing pretty ugly. It would be better if you could use a dot or just one word.

```
when dataValidFor clientName then addInfoToReport otherwise addErrorToReport
```

Resolves to

```
when(dataValidFor).clientName(then).addInfoToReport(otherwise).addErrorToReport
```

Which will be weird to parse. It is better if you could do something like:

```
when dataValidFor('clientName') then addInfoToReport otherwise addErrorToReport
```

I did the following:

```
report = [:]

// the closure passed as a parameter to the html component
Closure runningVerification

// the closure that handles adding info to report
Closure addInfoToReport = { Data data -> 
  report[data] = "[INFO] Field '$data.field' from component '$data.component' valid: $data.valid"
}

// the closure that handles adding errors to report
Closure addErrorToReport = { Data data -> 
  report[data] = "[ERROR] Field '$data.field' from component '$data.component' valid: $data.valid"
}

/*
 * The when() method will receive a data object and returns
 * a map to be handled by the 'then' and the 'otherwise' cases
 *
 * The 'then' and 'otherwise' must passes closures to this method
 */
def when(Data data) {
  data.component = runningVerification.binding.htmlComponent

  [ then: 
    { Closure thenAction -> 

      if (data.valid) thenAction(data) 

      [ otherwise: 
        { Closure otherwiseAction -> 
          if (!data.valid) otherwiseAction(data) 
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


/*
 * Handles missing method calls. We need this to keep track of the 
 * 'generalTab', the HTML component whose tests are being ran against
 */
def methodMissing(String method, args) 
{
  runningVerification = args[0]
  runningVerification.delegate = this
  runningVerification.binding.htmlComponent = method // awful
  runningVerification()
}


/*
 * Verify the status of the validation for html component. The
 * argument is useless, it needs to access the report variable in 
 * the binding
 */
def verify(dataValidation) {
  def errors = report.findAll { !it.key.valid }.size()
  report.each { println it.value }
  print "Result: "
  if (errors == report.size()) {
    println "Every test failed"
  } else if (errors == 0) {
    println "Success"
  } else {
    println "At least one test failed"
  }
}

class Data { String component; String field; Boolean valid }

Data dataValidFor(String property) { 
  new Data(valid: new Random().nextInt() % 2, field: property)
}

Data confidentialData(String property) { 
  new Data(valid: new Random().nextInt() % 2, field: property)
}


verify generalTab {
  when dataValidFor('clientName') then addInfoToReport otherwise addErrorToReport
  when dataValidFor('clientCountry') then addInfoToReport otherwise addErrorToReport
  when confidentialData('clientId') then addInfoToReport otherwise addErrorToReport
}
```

And it works. It prints (randomly):

```
[INFO] Field 'clientName' from component 'generalTab' valid: true
[ERROR] Field 'clientCountry' from component 'generalTab' valid: false
[INFO] Field 'clientId' from component 'generalTab' valid: true
Result: At least one test failed
```

It got pretty ugly. It's more of a proof of concept. You need to separate the classes using BaseScripts, GroovyShell, delegate it to other classes, and the likes. You will also need to model it neatly, considering a class for reports and so. But so far, i think it's doable. Rather large, though.

My reading suggestions:

Guillaume Laforge shows a script DSL for a robot in mars:
http://www.slideshare.net/glaforge/going-to-mars-with-groovy-domainspecific-languages

The art of Groovy's command expressions:
http://www.canoo.com/blog/2011/12/08/the-art-of-groovy-command-expressions-in-dsls/

This is an email i sent to the groovy list today, once i managed to finish a DSL over JFugue for my personal use:
http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Method-chaining-in-DSL-Instructions-td5711254.html

It's on github:
https://github.com/wpiasecki/glissando

Comment: Thanks a ton Will. This gives me a huge headstart. Seriously.

Comment: Had to say that the solution `when dataValidFor('clientName') then addInfoToReport otherwise addErrorToReport` is more like spoonfeeding me. Thanks a ton.

Comment: You are welcome :-). You know, something cool you could make (but only for syntax coolness, and not to really help) is to do something like `when clientName is valid` and `when clientId is hidden`. Odd number of words are easier to parse. Also you can use groovy's `propertyMissing(String)` to remove the single quotes from `'clientName'` if you want